# An optional reminder to select an answer after 2 days of the last answer upvoted?

Tags: feature-request

Often there are times when a particular answer satisfies my immediate needs, but I feel like its probably not the best way to do it. I upvote it, and wait for a day or so before marking it as answer if there are no better answers. However, for websites that I don't visit very frequently, I am suspicious of myself forgetting to mark the right answer, so don't wait a lot before marking the answer. This however, discourages further answers, partly because there's a satisfaction in answering when someone needs an answer! What I'd actually prefer is an optional reminder 48 hours after the last time I upvoted an answer on a question I asked. A one-click clock toggle in front of the check-mark?

Also, if no answer was upvoted but there was a self-answer then 48 hours after the self-answer was added.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I doubt SE will *ever* implement a feature request that has the words `optional` or `configurable` in it...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I figured its one-click, so not much configuration and choosing around to might be worth a proposal. Thank you for pointing it out though. Appreciate the discussion, and not "blind downvotes"

Comment: SE devs seem to have a dislike of optional settings... with good reason I guess - it would require adding another table (I think) in their db...

Comment: Yeah, and optional means they don't know what the user is likly to do. Remove the optional bit and this would be a good idea.

Comment: Am I to take downvotes to imply that the suggestion is stupid, or something else? A small comment with such votes would be proper etiquettes I think, unless you're having a bad day, in which case- my condolences.

Comment: @user148324 Meta votes on [tag:feature-request]s mean disagreement with the idea.

Comment: @Scimonster Thanks. I wonder if a comment should be added though. Drive-through votes aren't necessarily going to be about quality.

Comment: Hu? No, here down votes are that you disagree *or* it is low quality. In this case, perhaps a bit of both, but probably mainly the disagreement. You also don't want 10 comments saying "i disagree".

Comment: @Tim I disagree.

Comment: @Tim I just read the last sentence and felt compelled to write the comment that I did.  The irony was just more powerful than my self-restraint.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.

Your suggestion will actually let users have less time to try to make a better answer. Sometimes, patience will have to work. Some questions are easy to answer thus a shorter time the best answer shall show up. Yet some excellent questions require time for users to solve and show the best way to solve your problem. This seems to personal to you.

I recommend that you have your own little reminder set on your device to remind you. I say status-declined for me. Nothing against you and no offense.